# Do I need same monitor sizes and resolutions for multi monitor support

Tags: multiple-monitors, 12.04

I am testing 12.04 because it has better multi monitor support but I was wondering do I need to have the same size/resolution for it to work correctly.

For example the first monitor is a 32' TV with 1920x1080 resolution. Do I need another one with the same inches, resolution or both the same for it to work correctly.

Comment: I can't speak to 12.04, but I have used both 10.04 and 11.10 with dual monitors of differing resolutions.

Comment: The thing is, in 11.04 and 11.10 I have always had to do small configurations to fix some problems between big resolutions and small ones put together. I am hoping that 12.04 will solve many of my problems but just in case I want to know about this question to solve some doubt about it.

Comment: For me, the ease of setup depended far more on my video card than on which distro - my Nvidia card was *very* simple to set up, ATI/AMD card was not nearly as smooth.  (Obviously a sample size of 2 can't prove anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used multiple monitors for years on several platforms (debian, ubuntu, gentoo, and fedora) with both nvidia and ati. As long as the graphics card is compatible I have never had any major problem with using different resolutions for different monitors.

The minor problems are with background images that span more then one monitor, but now I typically set the background image with nitrogen, and as long as I do not span the image across multiple monitors, no problem.

Are you having a problem with 12.04 ?

Comment: When for example, I connect a CRT 14' monitor and the 32' TV, the bigger one changes resolution to adapt to the smaller one. What I want is a way for them to offer the biggest resolution and be able to be together without affecting the others resolution. This should be independent of the resolution of both so for example the big one is 1920x1080 and the small one 1024x768 then they should be together and if i move something from one side to the other it should adapt to the size.  Something like resolution scaling support between monitors.

Comment: Can you set the resolution you desire with xrandr ?

Comment: I was just researching that with xrandr just to kill my doubts.

Comment: See if my blog helps: http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/use-xrandr-to-set-a-screen-resolution/ I listed some graphical tools that may help as well.

Comment: That would answer this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107085/how-to-set-resolutions-with-xrandr-using-multiple-monitors Specially the part about dual monitor.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't need to, although it does work a bit better if you use the same resolutions in a multi monitor set up.