# How to set resolutions with xrandr using multiple monitors

Tags: 11.10, xrandr

I want to set specific resolutions to 2 monitors. How can I tell xrandr which monitor to change resolution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First list your monitors and resolutions:

```
xrandr -q
```

Take note of your monitors names, example (I truncated the output so as to not list all the resolutions)

```
bodhi@zenix:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
1920×1200 60.0*+

DVI-I-2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
1920×1200 60.0*+
```

Here my monitors are "DVI-I-1" and "DVI-I-2"

With that information you can then set a resolution. Use "--output" and "--mode" to set each monitor's resolution.

```
xrandr --auto --output DVI-I-2 --mode 1920x1200 --left-of DVI-I-1
```

See [my blog post](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/use-xrandr-to-set-a-screen-resolution/) and/or [man xrandr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xrandr.1.html) for additional options (setting a resolution or dpi or frequency).

Post back, with the output of `xrandr -q` if you require specific help with your monitors.

Note: xrandr does not work with proprietary drivers.