# Can't set the resolution of my monitor on DisplayPort

Tags: xorg, xrandr, displayport

My graphics card has a DVI port and two Display Ports. I have two of the same monitors, one on DVI, one on DP, but can't get xrandr to set the resolution on the DP one. I can't use `xrandr --addmode` directly to DP-0 without getting an error:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1952 x 864, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1152x864+800+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384       119.9    119.6  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384       120.0  
   400x300       144.4  
   320x240       120.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.3*+
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1368x768_60.00 (0x33c)   85.2MHz
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.9Hz
  1360x768_60.00 (0x357)   84.8MHz
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
  1024x768_60.00 (0x395)   63.5MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock   59.9Hz
  1280x800_60.00 (0x3b3)   83.5MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock   59.8H
```

Here is the error:

```
$ xrandr --addmode DP-0 1360x768_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Comment: can you post the command you are using (in addition to the error message)?

Comment: does this work - http://askubuntu.com/questions/107085/how-to-set-resolutions-with-xrandr-using-multiple-monitors